# PropertyNotFoundException Primefaces JavaEE

Tags: jsf, primefaces, java-ee

estoy intentando abrir una vista en un dialog con primefaces, ya tengo listo mi servicio, y vistas, lo hice basandome en la documentacion de Dialog Framework para ver como era su funcionamiento, pero me encuentro con los siguientes errores:

```
WARNING: #{dfView.viewMiembros}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/index.xhtml @22,38 action="#{dfView.viewMiembros}": Target Unreachable, identifier [dfView] resolved to null
javax.faces.FacesException: #{dfView.viewMiembros}: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/index.xhtml @22,38 action="#{dfView.viewMiembros}": Target Unreachable, identifier [dfView] resolved to null

jun. 14, 2020 5:52:41 P. M. com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /views/index.xhtml @22,38 action="#{dfView.viewMiembros}": Target Unreachable, identifier [dfView] resolved to null
```

Esta es mi clase dfView, omiti algunas partes para no hacer tan extenso el codigo.

```
@Named("dfView")
@RequestScoped
public class dfView {

    public void viewMiembros() {
        Map<String, Object> options = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        options.put("resizable", false);
        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().openDynamic("viewMiembros", options, null);
    }


    public void showMessage() {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "xxxx", "xxxxx");

        PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo primero es que el nombre de la clase debería ser `DfView`, empezando en mayúscula. Eso es una convención java y CDI/JSF se basa mucho en convenciones; cogerá el nombre de la clase y creará el bean como *dfView*. No creo que eso sea el error que te molesta, pero es un error y por probar. Y el atributo del @Named sobra (si la clase es *DfView*, el nombre CDI será *dfView* automáticametne).

Comment: Además, estaría bien que indicaras versión del servidor y JDK, y qué clase es realmente RequestScoped

Comment: Hola, la version del JDK que manejo es la 8 y el servidor que estoy utilizando es Glassfish 5.0.0, respecto a lo de RequestScoped no lo entiendo bien, me guie por la documentacion del Dialog Framework

Comment: Por ahora aunque renombre el dfView y quite el named, sigue saliendo el mismo error.